# $\overline{SAT}$ vs. $UNSAT$, Is it the same?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, co-np

I know this question may look stupid, but still..
Is the meaning of both "have no satisfiable assignment"?

Answer (score 3):

They are not *precisely* the same language. For instance, $\overline{SAT}$ has words that are not even formulas. $UNSAT$ on the other hand, has *only* formulas that are not satisfiable.

In terms of complexity measures - the two languages are equivalent, since we can check in polynomial time whether a given input word is a formula or not and therefore we have a poly-time reduction from $\overline{SAT}$ to $UNSAT$ and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks man! great answer, simple and clear!!